# Chrome web driver is closing with extensions, why?

Tags: python, google-chrome-extension, discord, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to do a Discord bot, that works with Google driver. Google Chrome is crashing when I add extensions there.

Chrome version:  113.0.5672.127 (Официальная сборка), (64 бит)
chromedriver.exe: ChromeDriver 113.0.5672.63

It works with this:

```
chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-infobars')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-notifications')
    #chrome_options.add_argument(rf'user-data-dir=C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default')
    chrome_options.add_argument("--profile-directory=Default")
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
    chrome_options.add_argument("--mute-audio")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--verbose")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--log-path=chrome.log")
```

but if I don't comment

```
#chrome_options.add_argument(rf'user-data-dir=C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default')
```

this it won't work. This line is adding Tamper Monkey extension and in it there is script that I need.

Here is full code:

```
@bot.command()
async def rank(ctx, rank_value, link, team):
    worksheet = workbook.active
    accounts = []

    # Создаем объект сервиса ChromeDriver
    chrome_driver_path = r'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\hashkey\chromedriver.exe'
    service = Service(chrome_driver_path)

    # Опции Chrome
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-infobars')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-notifications')
    #chrome_options.add_argument(rf'user-data-dir=C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default')
    chrome_options.add_argument("--profile-directory=Default")
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
    chrome_options.add_argument("--mute-audio")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--verbose")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--log-path=chrome.log")

    try:
        # Обрабатываем аккаунты
        for row in worksheet.iter_rows(values_only=True):
            if row[1] == rank_value:
                account = {
                    'number': row[0],
                    'hash_key': row[2],
                    'username': row[3]
                }
                accounts.append(account)
                if len(accounts) == 3:
                    await process_accounts(ctx, accounts, link, team, service, chrome_options)
                    accounts = []
        if accounts:
            await process_accounts(ctx, accounts, link, team, service, chrome_options)

    finally:
        service.stop()


async def process_accounts(ctx, accounts, link, team, service, chrome_options):
    drivers = []

    try:
        # Обрабатываем аккаунты
        for account in accounts:
            driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)
            drivers.append(driver)

            url = f'https://{account["number"]}.tankionline.com/play/'
            await ctx.send(f"Успешно произведен вход на аккаунт {account['username']}.")
            driver.execute_script(f"window.open('{url}', '_blank')")

        for driver in drivers:
            driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
            WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'body')))
            # Установить значение hash key в локальное хранилище
            driver.execute_script(f'window.localStorage.setItem("entrance_hash_key", "{account["hash_key"]}");')
            # Дождаться появления кнопки
            element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'ksc-0')))
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
            await asyncio.sleep(15)
            driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'body').send_keys(Keys.TAB)
            time.sleep(1)
            button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="root"]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]')))
            time.sleep(1)
            button.click()
            time.sleep(1)
            chat_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@type='text']")))
            chat_input.send_keys(link, Keys.ENTER)
            time.sleep(2)
            elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="root"]/div[3]/div[3]')
            last_element = elements[-1]
            links = last_element.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'a')
            last_link = links[-1]
            last_link.click()
            time.sleep(4)
            body = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "body")))
            body.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
            time.sleep(1)
            actions = ActionChains(driver)
            actions.key_down(Keys.ALT).send_keys('9').key_up(Keys.ALT).perform()
            driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('tanki__tools_glitch').checked = true;")
            time.sleep(3)
            await ctx.send(f"Аккаунт {account['username']} кликается в битву.")
            if team == 'A':
                click_A(driver)
            elif team == 'B':
                click_B(driver)
            elif team == 'both':
                wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 3600)
                button_xpath = "//div[@id='tanki__tools_teams']/button[1]"
                element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, button_xpath)))
                element.click()
                button_xpath = "//div[@id='tanki__tools_teams']/button[2]"
                element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, button_xpath)))
                element.click()
                css_selector = '#root > div.ksc-0.ApplicationLoaderComponentStyle-container.Common-background'
                div = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, css_selector)))
                driver.execute_script("window.open('about:blank', '_self');")
                check_and_close_tab(driver)
            elif team == 'DM':
                click_DM(driver)

    finally:
        # Закрываем все вкладки и завершаем работу WebDriver
        for driver in drivers:
            driver.quit()
```